# stop encoding special characters in textarea on submit

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, urlencode

I want to stop text area from encoding special characters.

If I input `1:2#aa^bb` in text area then on submit it converts into `1%3A2%23aa%5Ebb`.

I want the text to be submitted, as it is, without any conversion.

Comment: Encoding is required for a valid GET/POST data. Server side languages such as PHP will see the data as you typed, not as it's encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Set the enctype on your form to `multipart/form-data` and the method to post

Answer (score 0):

If you have like `<textarea name="data">`, then when you submit it you see `...?data=1%3A2%23aa%5Ebb` and that's correct although modern browsers will superficially show the decoded version and you wouldn't have this non-problem.

When you do `request.getParameter("data")` on server-side, you will see it is `"1:2#aa^bb"`. I assume JSP/Servlets from your profile.

Comment: request.getParameter("data") gives data in encoding form

Comment: @Surya ok you should really show some code. `escape` will encode it even more xD

Answer (score -1):

try `escape(string)` while submitting the textarea value

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. `escape` applies non-standard URI encoding to a string. If anything, stuff like this is **the cause** of his original problem.

Comment: escape won't help but decode did it's work like strdataString = URLDecoder.decode(strdataString,"ISO-8859-1");